# Best way to analyze MS Server 2008 R2 Task Manager?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Looking to keep metrics on my MS Server 2008 R2 - some specific items in the task manager.  I have several processes that are appearing to stay open and consuming lots of memory.

What's the best way to measure the memory used by these processes and report them?

Thanks in advance!

M

Comment: SQL Server is only one process - sqlservr.exe. If you have other processes using memory then it's nothing to do with sql server. If sqlservr.exe is using lots of memory - that's normal as it uses as much memory as you have configured it to use. So are you trying to optmimise SQL Server or the server that SQL Server is running on?

Comment: You should never use task manager to measure SQL Server memory consumption it does not always gives correct value, specially whem `LPIM is there` for SQL Server service account. Instead use `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory` if you have SQl Server 2008 and above.

Comment: Thanks, Shanky!  I'll use this instead!